# Writing a constructor for jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I write a constructor for a jQuery plugin? why this.Viewer.init() is not working here?

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.testing= function(options){
        var settings = {
            'url'            : null
        };   
    if(options){$.extend(settings, options)};    
    var Viewer = {
        init: function(){
            console.log('Lorem ipsum dolor');
        }
    };    
    };
    this.Viewer.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Console.log

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Comment: Why would it work, `this.Viewer` is not defined, just do `Viewer.init();`

Answer (score 2):

You defined `Viewer` as a local variable, not a property, when you access `Viewer` you don't need to use `this`:

```
Viewer.init();
```

Comment: don't get confused by his tabbing, `this.Viewer.init` is actually outside of the plugin function. simply removing `this.` isn't enough

Comment: @KevinB, i should probably left this as a comment, but the purpose was to fix the "Uncaught TypeError..." issue and nothing more.